# How can I be notified when the text of a TextBlock changes

Tags: windows-runtime

In WinRT, is there a way to be notified when the text of a TextBlock changes?

I don't see a TextChanged event.

Answer (score 1):

TextBlocks aren't editable (read-only). So, there's not a TextChanged event like there is for a TextBox. If you need to know when the text has changed, you'll need to wire up a listener to the source of data (maybe through PropertyChanged for example).